# Can I host a website on GitHub Pages if it calls an API to display data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, github-pages, web-hosting

I'm creating a portfolio website with ReactJS that I plan on hosting on GitHub Pages. In my projects section, I want to access the GitHub API to automatically show some information about my repositories (name, description, link, demo). Is this possible with GitHub pages, or does it fall into the category of a dynamic webpage (which cannot be hosted on GitHub pages)?

Comment: When you say "which cannot be hosted on GitHub pages", are you referring to the GitHub Pages Terms of Service, or are you talking about how you cannot have a custom server due to the limitations of the GitHub pages itself?

Comment: Can the API be accessed from your frontend or do you need a backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this should work.
Even though the Frontend-Files are static you are not actually serving your own API which would need a separate application Server. You are only consuming an API from another Server.